# How to position a div in a Jquery UI slider by giving ui.values

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a requirement that I need to create a div which looks like the range in  Jquery UI slider, and we should be able to position it on the slider based on inputs(values, as we give to position the handlers) given by the users 
It will not move with the slider but will be static.

```
$("#slider-range").slider({
    step: 0.01,
    'min': 10,
    'max': 50,
    range: false,
    //rangeValues: [11.2,30.1],
    values: [45.1, 18.1],
    slide: function (event, ui) {
 //  return false;
    }
});
```

I am looking for something like this where I have created my own "rangeValues" option to which we supply values just like we do for the handles and it should be placed on the slider, based on the values provided and not the css.
any help will be highly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you are looking for something like this : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RR6gP/5/)**

Div that moves based on *ul values*, correct me if i'm wrong

```
    $('#responsiveDiv').css('left', ui.value+'px');
```